# How to make the user pay for something online

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am making a bookstore website and I want the user to be able to pay for the books online with credit card or visa etc .. how to do this in django is there a library for this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several payment packages available in Django with different facilities.

I will suggest you to use **[DJ-STRIPE](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable-2.0/)** so many cool features available in it, for which you can have a look on their official documentation.

> But there are various other packages to process the payments in Django with different features and functionality.

You can have a look on all of those here. **[Django Payments Packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/payment-processing/)**.

**In most cases, you will need a merchant account and attached bank account to accept the payment.**